# Is a system composed of LTI causal systems is also causal?

Tags: linear

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2uE3A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a question which for which I could not find answer.

Let us say we have A and B which are LTI and causal systems.

Can I say that system Q which is composition of A and B (in a circuit) is also causal?

Comment: maybe depending on exactly what you mean by 'composition', I don't see how two causal systems composed in any reasonable way could be anything other than causal. Now, with what level of rigour do you want your proof? And what do I mean by 'reasonable'?

Comment: hmm, By composition I will edit the post, I will add the Graph if it is possible ( I will try now )
But if you say it is Casualy, it is good :)  
About proof, I dont really need actually, It will be good for me, but it is  not necceseary if it is a problem \ may take long for you ( Since I just needed to know this )

Comment: Sorry for asking, but is this a homework? Are you asking for a formal proof of the statement?

Comment: It is alright, I dont need a formal proof, just for me to know, I just thought of this and it seems true, but without proof, I must make sure, so I thought I will ask here :)

Comment: @Neil_UK Hi, Added the circuit, Although as said, it doesnt really matter what circuit, I happened to think of it at this circuit I saw, but what I said is true for all right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Regarding a composition of casual system (cascading them)

The [definition of a causal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_system) is that:

> A system \$F\$ is causal if for any signals \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ and **any** time \$t_0\$ we have that \$x_1(t)=x_2(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$ implies that \$F(x_1(t))=F(x_2(t))\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$.

Where the \$x\$'s are input signals to the system/circuit \$F\$ that generates the output signal \$F(x_1)(\cdot)\$.

Now, if you have two causal systems \$F\$ and \$G\$ and compose them you obtain another system \$H(\cdot) = F(G(\cdot))\$. This system will be causal, and to show it we start with:

- (1) for any signals \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ and **any** time \$t_0\$ such that \$x_1(t)=x_2(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$

Since \$G\$ is causal, statement (1) implies that:

- (2) \$G(x_1)(t)=G(x_2)(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$

Since \$F\$ is causal, assumption (2) implies that:

- (3) \$F(G(x_1))(t)=F(G(x_2))(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$.

Since \$H(\cdot) = F(G(\cdot))\$, from statement (1) and the implication chain up to (3) we have that: for any signals \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ and time \$t_0\$ such that \$x_1(t)=x_2(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$ we have that \$H(x_1)(t)=H(x_2)(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$. So we do have that \$H\$ is causal.

#### Examples

Given two causal systems \$F\$ and \$G\$ we can show that \$F+G\$, adding the output of the systems, and \$F \star G\$, the convolution of the outputs of the systems, will also be causal.

1. First we show that the system \$A\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}\right) = x_1 + x_2 \$, adding the inputs at each instant, is causal. That should be intuitive since the output at any instant is just the sum of the inputs at that same instant.
2. The convolution normally used in circuits analysis and control systems is the one-sided convolution of two signals, it is defined as
   $$ (x_1 \star x_2)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t x_1(\tau) x_2(t-\tau)  d\tau. $$
   Notice that it only uses values/information of the two signals \$x_1, x_2\$ from before or at time \$t\$, so it will be causal. Lastly, define \$B\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}\right) = x_1 \star x_2\$.
3. The compositions \$A\left(\begin{bmatrix}F(x_1) \\ G(x_2)\end{bmatrix}\right)=F(x_1)+G(x_2)\$ and \$B\left(\begin{bmatrix}F(x_1) \\ G(x_2)\end{bmatrix}\right) = F(x_1) \star G(x_2)\$ will be causal from all the systems being causal and the argument that composing/cascading causal systems leads to another causal system.

#### Regarding feedback loops

The analysis above does not hold for a feedback system, as the feedback loop, first and foremost, creates also the problem of the loop [being well-posed or not](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Dynamic_Systems_and_Control_(Dahleh_Dahleh_and_Verghese)/17%3A_Interconnected_systems_and_feedback-_well-posedness_stability_and_performance/17.02%3A_Well_Posedness). An example of an ill-posed system would be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGqpJF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and the issue becomes clear once we write the equations that "relate" the input to the output
$$ x(t)+y(t)=y(t) $$
which would imply that \$x(t) = 0\$, the input having to always be zero!

I couldn't find any simple source on why well-posed causal linear systems are causal, but here is a non-rigorous sketch:

- A linear system \$A(x+By) = y\$ (the plant is \$A\$, the transfer function on the feedback loop is \$B\$, and the summing junction is adds the feedback to the input) will be well-posed if the system \$(I-AB)\$ is invertible (for any signal \$y\$, the whole output signal \$y\$ leads to a unique input signal \$Ax\$ such that \$Ax = (I-AB)y\$.
- From linearity we have that for any signals \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ and **any** time \$t_0\$ such that \$x_1(t)=x_2(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$, the signals \$y_{x_1}\$ and \$y_{x_2}\$ can only differ up to time \$t_0\$ on the nullspace of \$(I-AB)\$, but that system is invertible so the nullspace of \$(I-AB)\$ will be just the zero signal (a signal that is zero for any time \$t\$).
- We have that \$y_{x_1}\$ and \$y_{x_2}\$ are equal up to time \$t_0\$.
- This all leads to the linear system made of causal systems with a well-posed loop being causal, that is, it holds that

> for any signals \$x_1\$, \$x_2\$ and **any** time \$t_0\$ with \$x_1(t)=x_2(t)\$ for all time \$t\$ up to \$t_0\$, we have that \$y_{x_1}=y_{x_2}\$ up to time \$t_0\$

For in-depth discussion on the challenges to determine if the feedback of nonlinear systems is well-posed I can only refer to
https://doi.org/10.1109/CDC.1987.272730 and https://doi.org/10.1109/9.40742 which were the only papers I could find on the topic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proof :)
Much Appreciated!!

Comment: Can you clarify how your proof covers \$H(s)=F(s)+G(s) or H(s)=F(s)G(s)\$? Maybe I don't understand what is meant by "compose". Furthermore, can you clarify where \$F(s)\$ is causal to \$t_0\$ but \$G(s)\$ is causal to \$t_1\$?

Comment: @RussellH, I added some extra info. By compose I mean "cascade", as in to plug the output of circuit G to the input of circuit F. The causality should hold for any two signals and "reference time" \$t_0\$, if the is a counter example (a pair of signals and a specific \$t_0\$) for which the implication does not hold then the system is not causal.